# Python, elif error when running within a input

Tags: python

Every time I run this code, I get an error on the `elif` in the middle and I have tried fixing this by adjusting the spacing, etc.

```
print("Do you want to find the area of a triangle or trapezoid?")
shape = input()

if shape = "Triangle" or "triangle":
    height = float(input("Please enter the height of the triangle: "))
    base = float(input("Please enter the base length of the triangle: "))
    area = 0.5 * height * base
    print("The area of a triangle with height", height, "and base", base, "is", area, ".")
  elif shape = "Trapezoid" or "trapezoid":
      height_1 = float(input("Please enter the Height of the trapezoid: "))
      base_1 = float(input('Please enter the base one value: '))
      base_2 = float(input('Please enter the base two value: '))
      area_1 = ((base_1 + base_2) / 2) * height_1 #This line is the math for figuring the area of the triangle
    print("The area of the Trapezoid height", height_1, "and bases", base_1, "and", base_2, "is", area_1, ".")
  else:
    print("Wrong shape or misspelled shape. Please check it again!")
```

Comment: isn't the condition an assignment instead?

Comment: What error and where and why the gis tag ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to do `==` with `lower`:

```
print("Do you want to find the area of a triangle or trapezoid?")
shape = input()

if shape.lower() == "triangle":
    height = float(input("Please enter the height of the triangle: "))
    base = float(input("Please enter the base length of the triangle: "))
    area = 0.5 * height * base
    print("The area of a triangle with height", height, "and base", base, "is", area, ".")
elif shape.lower() == "trapezoid":
    height_1 = float(input("Please enter the Height of the trapezoid: "))
    base_1 = float(input('Please enter the base one value: '))
    base_2 = float(input('Please enter the base two value: '))
    area_1 = ((base_1 + base_2) / 2) * height_1 #This line is the math for figuring the area of the triangle
    print("The area of the Trapezoid height", height_1, "and bases", base_1, "and", base_2, "is", area_1, ".")
else:
    print("Wrong shape or misspelled shape. Please check it again!")
```

Comment: My answer would have mimic'd this , thumbs up

Comment: haha aran called me out my explanation was 'Do this', I responded with I was being lazy hahaha

Comment: @vash_the_stampede lol, hahaha, unlike some people just here to write novels :-)

Comment: @vash_the_stampede Those make me dizzy

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to clean your code.
As first you need to understand the differences between the '=' operator and the '==' operator. The first performs an assignment:

```
a = "Hello World"
b = 7
```

In python, it means that a is a pointer to a memory area that contains the String value 'Hello World' and b is a pointer to a memory area that contains the int value '7'. Python is strongly but dinamically typed and i would not suggest to start programming with this language, indeed it has lots of feature you would enjoy becoming an expert!
The operator '==' is a boolean operator between 2 values, in mathematic we would say that '==' maps two values from the same domain (they must have the same type!) to the {TRUE,FALSE} domain. It is a boolean expression that returns TRUE if and only if the 2 values you give it are equals. Here we have a first problem with python, because it is contrary to teaching. In fact:

```
7 == 7 #True!
a = 7
a == 7 #True!
a = "Hello World"
a == "Hello World" #True!
```

7 and 7 are both integer values, and they are the same value, so yes, it is true that 7 is equal to 7! But if a is a pointer, and 7 is a value, it is true that a == 7 but a is a Pointer, and 7 is a value! More deeply. If a = "Hello World" it is true, in python, that a == "Hello World", but this is not true in mathematic (since the a domain and the "Hello World" domain are different) and this is not true in every other OOP language (such as java or c++) because 'a' and 'Hello World' are DIFFERENT OBJECTS representing the same value!

Now that it is clear the difference between the '=' and the '==' operators, we could talk about your problem. It is a good practice, in programming, to declare strings "a priori", and call them wherever you want in the code. This leads to a more readable and maintainable code (modify once, modify everywhere).

```
ask = "Do you want to find the area of a triangle or trapezoid?\n"
askheight = "Plase enter the height of the triangle: "
askbase = "Please enter the base length of the triangle: "
asktrapheight = "Please enter the height of the trapezoid: "
askminbase = "Plase enter the minor base value: "
askmajbase = "Plase enter the major base value: "
areas = "The area of the shape is: "
ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION = "Wrong shape or misspelled shape. Please check it again!"
```

Then, the input. You want to read a string, not an integer. So the function you need is the 'raw_input()'. If your program doesn't need to be case sensitive, I suggest also to convert the input in lowercase and manage only lowercases string in your code:

```
shape = raw_input(ask)
shape = shape.lower()
```

At this point, you want to check the validity of the user input, that is, a great way to reach robustness! Always do this as the first, in order to manage the "runtime exception" istantly. Define this function:

```
def illegalArgument(shape):
    if shape == "triangle" or shape == "trapezoid":
        return False
    return True
```

And call it after your input:

```
if illegalArgument(shape):
    raise Exception(ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION)
```

Now you are ready to perform your task:

```
if shape == "triangle":
    height = float(input(askheight))
    base = float(input(askbase))
    area = 0.5*height*base
else:
    height = float(input(asktrapheight))
    basemin = float(input(askminbase))
    basemaj = float(input(askmajbase))
    area = ((basemin+basemaj)/2)*height
print(area+str(area))
```

Also note this:

```
print(areas+str(area))
```

The '+' operator between strings means that you are joining the two strings. Indeed:

```
"Hello"+"World" #it is "HelloWorld"
```

But we have 'areas' as String, and 'area' as an integer! So the '+' operator between strings and integers won't reduce to a value since it is an illegal operation at runtime, and your program will crash. The function 'str(area)' transform the integer value to a string, and the '+' operation is type-safe.

Here it is the entire code:

```
def illegalArgument(shape):
    if shape == "triangle" or shape == "trapezoid":
        return False
    return True
if __name__ == '__main__': #Just another python good practice!
    ask = "Do you want to find the area of a triangle or trapezoid?\n"
    askheight = "Plase enter the height of the triangle: "
    askbase = "Please enter the base length of the triangle: "
    asktrapheight = "Please enter the height of the trapezoid: "
    askminbase = "Plase enter the minor base value: "
    askmajbase = "Plase enter the major base value: "
    areas = "The area of the shape is: "
    ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION = "Wrong shape or misspelled shape. Please check it again!"
    shape = raw_input(ask)
    shape = shape.lower()
    if illegalArgument(shape):
        raise Exception(ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION)
    if shape == "triangle":
        height = float(input(askheight))
        base = float(input(askbase))
        area = 0.5*height*base
    else:
        height = float(input(asktrapheight))
        basemin = float(input(askminbase))
        basemaj = float(input(askmajbase))
        area = ((basemin+basemaj)/2)*height
    print(areas+str(area))
```

good luck for your studies!

Answer (score 0):

When you compare two values in python, you use `==`, not `=`.

`=` is an assignment operator, not a comparison operator.

Also, you can't do `x == y or z`. You have to do `x == y or x == z`

So, your `if` statement would become:

`if shape == "Triangle" or shape == "triangle":`

and your `elif` would become:

`elif shape == "Trapezoid" or shape =="trapezoid":`

Finally, your indentation is wrong, which is everything when talking about python conditionals.

Here is what your final code should look like:

```
print("Do you want to find the area of a triangle or trapezoid?")
shape = input()

if shape == "Triangle" or shape == "triangle":
    height = float(input("Please enter the height of the triangle: "))
    base = float(input("Please enter the base length of the triangle: "))
    area = 0.5 * height * base
    print("The area of a triangle with height", height, "and base", base, "is", area, ".")
elif shape == "Trapezoid" or shape == "trapezoid":
    height_1 = float(input("Please enter the Height of the trapezoid: "))
    base_1 = float(input('Please enter the base one value: '))
    base_2 = float(input('Please enter the base two value: '))
    area_1 = ((base_1 + base_2) / 2) * height_1 #This line is the math for figuring the area of the triangle
    print("The area of the Trapezoid height", height_1, "and bases", base_1, "and", base_2, "is", area_1, ".")
else:
    print("Wrong shape or misspelled shape. Please check it again!")
```

Besides this, there are many other issues with your code and its efficiency. For example, you can't concatenate strings the way you are doing it in your `print` statements. I recommend you read [the following string concatenation tutorial](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python) to learn how to fix what you have.

Answer (score 0):

the indentation is off on the `elif`, and you have a few other errors as well:

- for ***equal to*** you should use `==`
- for each condition that needs to meet your `if`, you need to type out
  the whole thing instead of just using `or` operator
- You will not be able to print type `float`, so convert to string for
  print

Try This:

```
print("Do you want to find the area of a triangle or trapezoid?")
shape = input()

if shape == "Triangle" or shape == "triangle":
    height = float(input("Please enter the height of the triangle: "))
    base = float(input("Please enter the base length of the triangle: "))
    area = 0.5 * height * base
    print("The area of a triangle with height "+ str(height) +" and base "+ str(base) +" is "+ str(area) +".")
elif shape == "Trapezoid" or shape == "trapezoid":
    height_1 = float(input("Please enter the Height of the trapezoid: "))
    base_1 = float(input('Please enter the base one value: '))
    base_2 = float(input('Please enter the base two value: '))
    area_1 = ((base_1 + base_2) / 2) * height_1 #This line is the math for figuring the area of the triangle
    print("The area of the Trapezoid height "+ str(height_1) +" and bases "+ str(base_1) +" and "+ str(base_2) +" is "+ str(area_1) +".")
else:
    print("Wrong shape or misspelled shape. Please check it again!")
```

**Also**: if you don't want to check for `upper` or `lowercase` than just use this:

```
if shape.lower() == "triangle":
```